# PyMuPdf (fitz) inaccessible in docker

Tags: python, docker, tesseract, python-tesseract, pymupdf

I'm trying to get some OCR done in a docker file and since I couldn't get it to work with Tesseract I tried refactor to use PyMuPdf instead. The error I get is quite simple:

```
File "/code/table.py", line 35, in <module>
    import fitz
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fitz'
```

On my local (windows) machine I'm able to get it running with code that looks like this

```
import fitz
pages = fitz.open(source_path)  # open document
for page in pages:
   page_data = page.get_textpage_ocr(language='eng', dpi=600, full=True)
<etc>
```

However in Docker the same exact code does not work.

Relevant parts of my Dockerfile look like this

```
FROM python:3.10
WORKDIR /code
COPY ./requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# install PyMupdf
RUN pip install pymupdf

COPY . .

CMD ["python", "./run.py"]
```

I also have pymupdf in my requirements file, but I install it separately just in case. Building the image gives no errors and works as it should.

Relevant parts of Docker-compose.yml

```
build: .
container_name: ocr
command: python ./run.py
volumes:
  - .:/code
  - type: bind
    source: "C:/Program Files/Tesseract-OCR/tessdata"
    target: /code/tessdata
```

And in my `.env` file I have a reference to the binded mount `TESS_DATA_PREFIX='/code/tessdata`

I've added `TESS_DATA_PREFIX` to my environment variables, although it does not seem necessary anymore, and the error happens way before I try to even use OCR.

Comment: When you map your current directory to `/code`, you hide what's in the directory in the image, including the modules you've installed in the Dockerfile.

Comment: If this were the case none of my code should work, but it does. Only pymupdf (fitz) is not imported correctly. Is this particular library somehow different in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was related to Docker not updating after changes during builds. Removed all containers and build cache and now it works.

EDIT: also, the correct ENV variable should be called `TESSDATA_PREFIX`, not `TESS_DATA_PREFIX`. This was my next error but after changing `.env` to the correct variable name the code works exactly as configured above.